# Dell Dimension 5100 capacitor problem

Tags: capacitor

Can I swap the 820 µF 6.3 V capacitor on a Dell motherboard with any 820 µF 6.3 V bought from a local electronics store or are there other characteristics of the capacitor that I have to take into account?

The PC was bought in 2005, so I can't find the exact looking capacitor that's on the board. The capacitor is near the bottom of the board away from the [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), so I am lead to believe that this would be dealing with the power supply.

One side of the capacitor says:

- 820 µF
- kZG
- 6.3 V

And the other side says:

- (M)105 °C
- 5(7)
- 3 V

Answer (score 2):

The main things you should try to match or beat are:

- Low [ESR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance). Cheap capacitors with high ESR tend to die quickly in cheap computers like most Dell computers.
- Higher temperature rating. The higher, the more heat they can take before dying.
- Higher voltage rating. Again, the higher, the more voltage they can withstand. 10 V would be the next rating up.

Capacitance should be the same and physical size as well, unless you have room to put in a bigger one, but that's rarely the case in a computer.

**Note**: Most of the same brand/size capacitors in the same area of your Dell 5100 are probably going to die soon due to [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague). Even if they haven't exploded or leaked, they might have bulged out at the top (so it's slightly round instead of flat). Some might even look brand new, but they will still be dead. You might want to pick up a few replacements just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your replacement (a) physically fits in and (b) is rated at the same temperature (this might be erring on the side of caution, but stuff inside laptops can get hot). Also make sure you put it in the right way round!

The part you describe is probably a Nippon Chemi-con KZG series 6.3V capacitor, which has a tan(delta) of 0.22 according to the data sheet. If your replacement does not have a massively higher ESR, it should work. If in doubt, the Nippon capacitors are readily available from online retailers or ebay.